# Design of a Notch filter in Python

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing

I'm trying to design an IIR Notch filter in python using numpy array and the scipy librairy to remove a sine tone from a imported wave file (I'm using the wave module to do so). My file was generated by Adobe audition : it is a pure sine @ 1.2 kHZ, sampled @  48, 96 or 192 kHz, in order to have a "pseudo-periodic" data for my circular fft (just ask if I'm not clear enough)

Here is the code I used to implement the coefficient of my filter (I get the coefficient from the article ["Second-order IIR Notch Filter Design and implementation of digital signal 
processing system" by C. M. Wang & W. C. Xiao](http://www.atlantis-press.com/php/download_paper.php?id=5887))

```
f_cut = 1200.0
wn = f_cut/rate    
r = 0.99
B, A = np.zeros(3), np.zeros(3)
A[0],A[1],A[2] = 1.0, -2.0*r*np.cos(2*np.pi*wn), r*r
B[0],B[1],B[2] = 1.0, -2.0*np.cos(2*np.pi*wn), 1.0
filtered = signal.lfilter(B, A, data_flt_R, axis=0)
```

Where `data_flt_R` is a numpy array containing my right channel in a float64 type, and `rate` is my sampling frequency. I plot the frequency response and the fft of my data using the matplotlib module to see if everything is ok.

```
N = len(data_flt_R)    

w, h = signal.freqz(B,A, N)
pyplot.subplot(2,1,1)
pyplot.semilogx(w*rate/(2*np.pi), 20*np.log10(np.absolute(h)))    

fft1 = fftpack.fft(data_flt_R, N)
fft_abs1 = np.absolute(fft1)
ref = np.nanmax(fft_abs1)
dB_unfiltered = 20*np.log10(fft_abs1/ref)

fft2 = fftpack.fft(filtered, N)
fft_abs2 = np.absolute(fft2)
dB_filtered = 20*np.log10(fft_abs2/ref)

abs = fftpack.fftfreq(N,1.0/rate)

pyplot.subplot(2,1,2)
pyplot.semilogx(abs,dB_unfiltered,'r', label='unfiltered')
pyplot.semilogx(abs,dB_filtered,'b', label='filtered')
pyplot.grid(True)
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.ylabel('power spectrum (in dB)')
pyplot.xlim(10,rate/2)
pyplot.xlabel('frequencies (in Hz)')
```

And here is what I get :

[image]

I don't understand the results and values I get before and after my fc. Shouldn't I get a plot which looks like the red one but whithout the main peak ? Why do I have a slope in HF? Is this linked with windowing?

Moreover, the result changes if I change my sampling frequency and/or the data length (16/24 or 32 bits). Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Have a look at the filtered signal in the time domain.  Your IIR filter will exactly remove the sinusoid, but there will be a couple of samples of startup transient at the very beginning of your signal.  The "filtered" spectrum looks close to an impulse, i.e. a couple of nonzero samples in the whole signal.  Also, note that your vertical axis is very large - it's rare to look at more than 100 dB (ratio of 100,000) on an amplitude scale.  That's why you can see the quantization differences between 16 and 32 bits.

Comment: I check the time representation of my filtered signal, and it is exactly what you expect. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to math.stackexchange